# IModelBinder with DataAnnotation Support

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders, custom-model-binder

We have to use a custom ModelBinder that implements IModelBinder. We cannot directly change this code at all. It currently doesn't have support for updating ModelState from the DataAnnotations of the model passed in. We want to subclass the ModelBinder and add that support. What do we need to do to add that support so it works like DefaultModelBinder works with DataAnnotations?

Comment: Can't you just inherit from `DefaultModelBinder`?

Comment: You will have to provide more details. How does the model binder that you are using looks like?

Comment: @Darin - There's nothing much to it. It does some serialization of the object. But, what I'd like to know is how you update the data annotations to the modelstate after you have the model populated.

Comment: @LukLed --We don't own the modelbinder code, so no

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.